# IF/AND statement with index-matching

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I had a very long nested-if statement, and the last nested-IF was an IF/AND statement with index matching. The formula worked fine (or so I thought), until a few weeks later when I needed to add another IF/AND statement with index-matching. Then the whole thing wouldn't even run because Excel thought I had too many arguments for the function.

So, this weekend I was putzing around with the formula, and I started parsing out bits and realized this IF/AND statement was only partially working.

Here's what I mean:

(my formula is in the Priority column (col C) of sheet 1)

If the STATUS(col. B) says Approved, I want my formula to index-match the priority from sheet 2, unless that cell is blank - then I want the priority on sheet 1 to say "Medium." If Status on sheet 1 doesn't say Approved, then I don't want my formula to do anything in that cell.

> =IF((AND(B2="Approved",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))="")),"Medium", INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)))

which goes in in col. C of sheet1:

[image: sheet 1.]

Here is sheet 2:

[image: sheet 2.]

Item 10 works well - Status is Approved and priority on sheet 2 is blank so col. C says "Medium."

But, col C for items 20 and 25 have been index-matched when they shouldn't - they're status is not Approved, so they should be left blank.

I had a couple of ideas about remedying this, but neither worked. One idea was to add an AND(B2="Approved") to the last index-match,

> =IF((AND(B2="Approved",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))="")),"Medium", (AND(B2="Approved",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)))))

Which just returns a bunch of TRUE or FALSE.

[image: TF]

I also tinkered with adding another IF into that last index-match bit, but I realized that it wouldn't be one cohesive IF statement anymore.

How can I change my formula to get it to work? Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm pretty new to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Test if "Approved" first.  If false return `""` if true then do the if for the index:

```
=IF(B2="Approved",IF(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))="","Medium", INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```